# Use Properties File with Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, properties-file

How can properties files be used with Apache Camel to refer to configurable properties. For example, if there's a route that reads files from a folder, how can that folder location be configured in a properties file. I'm using Java DSL.

Answer (score 4):

Camel has extensive properties support.

At the very simple case you can do the following:

```
PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
pc.setLocation("classpath:com/mycompany/myprop.properties");
context.addComponent("properties", pc);
```

myprop.properties:

```
route.start=file:///tmp/myfile
route.to=direct:whatever
```

And in your route you can use the `{{..}}` placeholder syntax to refer to properties.

```
from("{{route.start}}")
    .split()
    .process(whatever)
    .to("{{route.to}}")
```

If you're using spring and your properties file is loaded already you can skip the properties component definition and refer to properties directly.

Read the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html) for more info.